# Initialize CGContext

Tags: swift, pdfkit, ios11

I'm trying to initialize CGContext ([API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1456290-init))

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: documentsPath + "/datafile")
if let context = CGContext(url: url as CFURL) {
    // stuff      
}
```

But this gives me the error:

`Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGContext' with an argument list of type '(url: CFURL)'`

I've also tried `CGContext(url as CFURL)` as well as `CGContext.init(url as CFURL)`

If I add `mediaBox: nil` I get:
`Ambiguous reference to member 'init(data:width:height:bitsPerComponent:bytesPerRow:space:bitmapInfo:releaseCallback:releaseInfo:)`

Comment: Lookup the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1456290-init. The initializer takes *three* arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: documentsPath + "/datafile") as CFURLRef    
let context = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(url, nil, nil)
```

Comment: I thought that was optional for some reason.  Got it working with CGContext(url, nil, nil)